# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive this error with my contact form in rails:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

**View:**

```
     <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
     and so on.......
```

**Controller**

```
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end
 and so on....
```

I found related errors, but none of the solutions seems to fit my particular issue. Any clues to what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you verify that `@contact` is not `nil`? I'm guessing that your form is being rendered out from an action _other_ than `contacts#new`.

Comment: FWIW, the frustration you're feeling is shared by all who have learned to code – it's just a natural part of learning a foreign framework. I'm don't think it adds anything to your question to complain about it.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't have the following:

```
<%= form_for nil do |f| %>
<%= form_for [] do |f| %>
```

My guess here is that your `@contact` is set to `nil` and that it doesn't come from your `Contact#new` action.

FYI it would simply work if you do this:

```
<%= form_for Contact.new do |f| %>
```

Though it is **not recommended**.

You need to check that the view containing your form is actually rendered by the `new` action of your `ContactsController`.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre and to all of the others. It was a really simple issue that I had overlooked and overcomplicated. I didn't route to the correct path and had a little mixup of directories.

Comment: This did work! But curious, why is not recommended, and what is the de-facto better solution? I have the Contact#new action set in my controller, but without the fix here I still get this error.

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland The MVC logic in Rails is that controllers pass instance variables to the views. The `form_for` method needs an instance of a model in order to properly build the params hash after the form is submitted. Check out the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). You could use `Contact.new` in the view, but this breaks the MVC pattern, so you might as well skip the controller altogether and include more logic in the views.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where I had a form in a modal that made changes to a model that was different than what the background page was showing. Even though I had the required @contact = Contact.new in my Contact controller, I needed to add this code within the controller for the background page.

For example, I have a PhoneBook model and within my index view for PhoneBook I have a modal with a form that adds a contact to my Contact model. I need @contact = Contact.new within my index method in my PhoneBook controller:

```
class PhoneBook < ApplicationController

  def index
    @contact = Contact.new
    ...
  end
end
```

And then the form within my modal that is being shown on PhoneBook index.html has the same syntax as others have written:

```
<div id="phoneBook">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way that you can reroute the new,create,build...etc. action to the proper controller(contact) instead of taking care of it in the phone book controller?

Comment: The only thing I have in the PhoneBook controller that is related to Contact is the initialization of a new Contact object. This is a way to prevent the 'nil or empty' error from occurring. Everything else in the PhoneBook controller is related to PhoneBook actions (new, create, etc.). You can specify which controller and action you'd like to use at the top of your form with `<%= form_for @contact url: {controller: 'contact', action: 'create'} do |f| %>`

Answer (score 6):

I know this has an accepted answer, but that didn't solved my same issue(i didn't wanted to use new in my view) and i intend to post what solved mine.

**This is always a typo,** you can check your routes with `$rake routes` if routes are ok, than its some kind of type somewhere else.

In my case i was using sublime editor, and i had an extra def above the def new in my controller, i don't know how it got there, but it was there...Removing it solved my issue after about half hour of nail bitting... There can be any kind of typo causing this issue. This error just means that the new method is not being accessed, if it was being accessed it would have initialized the variable.

**I repeat, always a typo somewhere.**

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: In my case, I was catching an error on model.save then doing a 'render' of a new view.  So, using render just calls the view and not the 'new' action.

Comment: I had the same issue of the action being defined twice in the controller

Comment: this was the correct answer for me, I had a typo in the name of the variable in the controller's new method.

Answer (score 2):

If in fact your instance variable is supposed to be `nil`, you could use 
`:contact` instead of `@contact` and provide a path.

In your case, the code should be,

```
<%= form_for( :contact , :html => {:class => "form-horizontal", :role => "form"}, url: login_path) do |form| %>
```

The `login_path` is just an example and can be replaced as seen fit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but it was easy to repair. In your `#example posts_controler.rb` add the same line to find post like in edit. In my application it's

```
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

It doesn't work here becase I added it but did not save my changes ;).

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on where your new or create action is defined. I had the same issue, turned out i had to put the @Object = object.new command inside the page method.

For example..

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def home
    @applicant = Applicant.new
end

def about
end

def homeowner
end
```

end

I before defined a "new" and "create" method and had the action in them which is usual and i do in other instances. Still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have a Comment model, a CommentsController, a 'show' action and a 'show' view for the comment. I also have a '_show' partial rendered inside the 'show' view with following local:

```
:locals => {:comment => @comment}
```

and inside the '_show' partial I have a

```
<%= form_for(comment, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

which troughs the "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". I only could solve the problem by renaming the local:

```
:locals => {:new_comment => @comment}
```

and within the partial:

```
<%= form_for(new_comment, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

It seems using the same name for the Model and the partial local caused some conflict for me.