# Paperclip- Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am creating an application that allows a user after they sign in to upload a document. When I try to click on the view page I keep getting an `NoMethodError in Pages#about`
 `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

For my view code

```
  <%= form_for @document, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my `pages_controller.rb`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def new 
    @document = Document.new
end

def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    @document.save
end

private
def document_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:attachment).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
end
```

here is my `user.rb`

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :documents

end
```

Here is my `document.rb`

```
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user # -> allows you to call @user.documents
    has_attached_file :attachment 



@user.documents.each do |document|
    image_tag document.attachment.url #-> outputs the image
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853721/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-rails-4

Comment: @LukasEklund I tried that solution, putting a .new and it did not work  for my problem.

Comment: Hmm. The error would indicate that ```@document``` in the form_for is nil. You tried ```form_for Document.new``` and it raises the same error?

Comment: Yes I tried 
`<%= form_for @document.new, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>` and I still got the same error.

Comment: No, not ```@document.new``` because the error is telling you @document is nil. Try ```Document.new```. But you should really investigate why @document is nil. Perhaps the pages controller is not being used?

Comment: I tried, thanks so much for all of your help so far. I am getting an an `undefined method new' for Document:Module error`    I think my page controller is working but I attached it.                              `def new 
    @document = Document.new
end

def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    @document.save
end

private
def document_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:attachment).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
end`

Comment: Question re: the Document model: is that a typo, or is ```Class``` in uppercase in the file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44735/discussion-between-lukas-eklund-and-neils)

Comment: it appears your form is rendered by the `about` action, where the `@document` object is not initiated