# Rails slim form_for error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'm trying to create many absents at once (for different students) and I'm pretty new to rails. I keep getting an error that "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty".

I'm also wondering whether I need a new method at all.

Here is my form

```
= form_for @absent, url: absent_path, method: :post do |f|
  table.table
    thead
      tr
        th Name
        th Absent

    tbody
      - @students.each do |student|
        tr
          td = student.full_name
          td = f.check_box :student_ids, student.id, @absent.students.include?(student), name: "absent[student_ids][]", id: "student_id_#{student.id}"
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

Here is my controller

```
def new
  @absent = Absent.new
end

def create
  absent_params[:student_ids].each do |student_id|
    @absent = Absent.new(student_id: student_id)
    if @absent.save
      redirect_to absent_path
    else
      render :index
    end
  end
end

private

def absent_params
  params.require(:absent).permit(
    :student_ids
  )
end
```

Here is my schema:

```
create_table "absents", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "absents", ["student_id"], name: "index_absents_on_student_id", using: :btree

create_table "students", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Here are my models:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :absents, foreign_key: :student_id

end

class Absent < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: :student_id

end
```

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb and your models into your question? This would help tremendously.

Comment: your form related to new controller action? Where is you placed your form?

Comment: @Зелёный my form is in my index view for absent

Comment: @tpho add to your index action `@absent = Absent.new` and all should work as expect, other way to change `form_for @absent, ...` to the `form_for Absent.new, ....`

Comment: possible duplicate of [First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty - Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853721/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-rails-4)