# RoR 6: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm adding comments for my tweets in my application but I get this error in the view for the first line in my form.

```
    First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #1): <%= form_for [@tweet, @comment] do |f| %>
```

My routes

```
resources :tweets do
  resources :comments
  resources :likes
end
```

My model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tweet
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @tweet.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end
end
```

My form

```
    comments/_form.html.erb
    
<%= form_for [@tweet, @comment] do |f| %>
        
<p><%= f.label :body %><br>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<br>
<br>
<%= f.submit %>
        
<% end %>
```

My view (partial)

```
tweets/_tweets_index.html.erb

    <% @tweets.reverse.each do |tweet| %>
    ....
    
      <%= render tweet.comments %><br>
      Add a comment
      <%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
    <% end %>
```

In turn rendered to tweets/index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'tweets_index' %>
```

I changed the first line on the form as per previous questions here ..[@foo, @bar].. as above but it still does not work. What am I doing wrong? ty

**EDIT:** I have made some progress but the following error appears

My form

```
<%= form_for( :comment , :html => {:class => "form-horizontal", :role => "form"}, url: tweets_path) do |form| %>

<p><%= form.label :body %><br>
   <%= form.text_area :body %>
</p>
<br>
<br>
<%= form.submit %>

<% end %>
```

**Error**
:param is missing or the value is empty: tweet

```
def tweet_params
        params.require(:tweet).permit(:user_id, :content, { comments: [:body] })
      end 

        {"authenticity_token"=>"79mdlyIOZTUF8hzXhoOpzTHKhk+/5SBrfnUjnImtmek1HyXDA0U/+R6oEOYgmy4H+a2kEppasDDKBobvdpbQdg==", "comment"=>{"body"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Save Comment"}
```

Comment: Check if `@tweet` is not `nil` in both `new` and `create`

Comment: For your ref [similar ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853721/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-rails-4/39504859)

Comment: @t s I don't have a new action, just a create action in my comments controller. I don't have a "new" view, I just have the form which I am rendering elsewhere.

Comment: okay whatever the action is make sure your variable contains value `@tweet` , Add debugger (pry gem) and check what is the value of `@tweet`

Comment: Thanks I think I have made some progress, please see update

Comment: You don't have a tweet field in your form.

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that `@tweet` is nil. So wherever you render this form, make sure that in the respective controller action, you define `@tweet`.

Comment: @t s Thanks I think I have made some progress, please see update. I hope you can see what i'm trying to do...