# Rails ArgumentError 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

It's viewfile below

```
<%= form_for @new_question do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_field :body%>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It's controller below

```
   def new
        @new_question = Question.new
    end
```

I don't know why it throws error

Comment: It means `@new_question` is nil or empty... are you sure you're in the right view file/right controller action?

Comment: Actually I cloned it from my instructor's and when she ran it, worked well

Comment: Check all file names for the view and the controller. And you can debug with `binding.pry` or `raise`

Comment: View name is new.html.erb

Comment: There must be some directories issue or file name issue in your code. Follow this thread for help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18854363/7009747