# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error with my user registration form in **Rails**:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty)
```

**View:**

```
        <%= form_for User.new, url: create_user_path, method: :post do |f|  %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name, t("settings.account.fullname"), class: "form-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control #{form_is_invalid?(User.new, :name)}", placeholder: t("settings.account.fullname"), autofocus: "", required: "" %>
            <div class="invalid-feedback d-block"><%=User.new.errors.full_messages_for(:name).first %></div>
          </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.provider = @user_domain
  end
    and so on..
```

I'm new to ROR. Can any one help me with this please?

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853721/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-rails-4 it means `User.new` is not a record, which is a bit strange... If you write `<%= User %>` of `<%= User.first %>` above your form, what do you get ?

Comment: @Maxence - if you clobber the `.new` class method and don't call super you can get this strange behavior. `class Foo; def self.new; end; end; Foo.new.nil? == true`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the bizarre error message this is just not how you do forms in Rails.

Since you're passing `User.new` to the form it will always be bound to a new instance of User. That means that anything the user has entered into the form will blanked out on an invalid form submission. `User.new.errors.full_messages_for(:name).first` will give a nil error since  there are no validation messages on a record that has not been validated.

What you actually want is something like:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users
```

```ruby
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.provider = @user_domain

    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

```erb
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, t("settings.account.fullname"), class: "form-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control #{form_is_invalid?(User.new, :name)}", placeholder: t("settings.account.fullname"), autofocus: "", required: "" %>
    <% if @user.errors.has_key?(:name) %>
      <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
        <%= @user.errors.full_messages_for(:name).each do |msg| %>
          <p><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you just [follow the Rails conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) you do not need to specify the URL or the method which are derived from the record. This lets you reuse the same form for updating existing records without changing anything in your code.

`create_user_path` is in itself extremely unidiomatic as Rails doesn't have a separate path for creating records. You create records by sending a POST request to the collection path (`/users`).

Comment: `form_for` isn't quite deprechiated yet but was replaced by `form_with` way back in Rails 5.2. Don't use it.